# How to make an iterable class in Python in which only a specific type is allowed to be the element?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I want some Python class having similar methods as `list` (assuming it's called `mylist`) except that `mylist` accepts elements of a specific type (instances of another customed class to store some data in my case).

I read some posts on SO and knew that I need to override some methods as `append`, `extend`, `insert`. But I'm not sure about everything I need to override to guarantee that in all operations (e.g. append, add, extend, insert, slice...) to instances of `mylist` there will be no problem.

And if there is one more convenient way without needs to override so many methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, things are easier without inheriting from builtin objects...:

```
from collections import MutableSequence, Iterable

class MyList(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, type, iterable=()):
        self._data = []
        self._type = type
        self.extend(iterable)

    def insert(self, index, item):
        if not isinstance(item, self._type):
            raise TypeError
        self._data.insert(index, item)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        return self._data.__getitem__(*args)

    def __delitem__(self, *args):
        self._data.__delitem__(*args)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         if isinstance(value, collections.Iterable) and isinstance(key, slice):
             values = []
             for val in value:
                 if not isinstance(value, self._type):
                     raise TypeError
         else:
             if not isinstance(value, self._type):
                 raise TypeError
         self._data[k] = value
```

---

Note, I haven't gone into any discussion about whether this is a *good idea*.  Some people will tell you not to do this because python is built on "duck-typing".  Others say that `isinstance` is perfectly fine to use -- provided that you do so responsibly.  One proponent of this view (Alex Martelli) is generally regarded as a python expert.  He recommends `isinstance` checking against abstract base classes and calls this practice "goose-typing".  This practice seems to have gained some traction as the standard library is slowly adding support that would allow more robust run-time checking of these things -- Consider [PEP-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) (type hinting).

I suppose, my point is that if you use this class, don't do:

```
lst1 = MyList(list)
lst2 = MyList(int)
```

Do something like:

```
lst1 = MyList(collections.MutableSequence)
lst2 = MyList(numbers.Integral)
```

Comment: `self._data.index(index, item)` should be `self._data.insert(index, item)`?

Comment: `self.extend(iterable)` be `self._data.extend(iterable)`? I don't get the last examples. Do they intend to convert the type from MutableSequence to MyList?

Comment: @Dr.Lee No.  If you did `self._data.extend(iterable)`, then those elements would go into your data list un-checked.  using `self.extend` makes sure that they are checked properly (although the default implementation probably isn't as efficient as you could write yourself).

Comment: @Dr.Lee With regard to the last examples, `lst1 = MyList(list)` makes sure that ever element that you put in is a `list` (or subclass of `list`).  however, as I've demonstrated here, it's pretty easy to make something that *looks* like a list using `collections.MutableSequence` -- so it's best to check for things that behave like `list` rather than checking if the thing is a `list`.  (note, `isinstance([], collections.MutableSequence)` is `True`).

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.