# How to allow only elements of a specific class to be elements of an iterable (for a custom class)

Tags: python, class, oop, tuples

In my case, I want to define a custom class (called WordTuple) which is a subclass of the tuple class. The elements of this custom tuple must all be of another custom class(called Word).

I know that this question ([How to make an iterable class in Python in which only a specific type is allowed to be the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766836/how-to-make-an-iterable-class-in-python-in-which-only-a-specific-type-is-allowed)) is similar, but the answer is not what I am looking for, nor it is very clear to me.

```
class Word(str):
    pass

class WordTuple(tuple):
    # Here whatever is necessary for the elements of this particular tuple
    # to be all members of the class 'Word'
    pass
```

Comment: Can't you enforce it in the __init__ ? Each time this class is initialized you can verify the data types using isinstance

Comment: @orizis The standard built-in immutable types get initialized in the `__new__` method rather than in `__init__`. There's more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452178/what-can-init-do-that-new-cannot)

Comment: @PM2Ring Cool, good to know. Thanks for alerting me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a tuple is immutable you only need to validate the objects when creating the tuple. You can do so in a custom [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

```
class WordTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *objs):
        if not all(isinstance(o, Word) for o in objs):
            raise TypeError('WordTuple can only contain Word instances')
        return super().__new__(cls, objs)
```

Demo:

```
>>> WordTuple('a', 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __new__
TypeError: WordTuple can only contain Word instances
>>> WordTuple(Word('a'), Word('b'))
('a', 'b')
```